Understanding cellular boundary formula
In Hatcher's book, the cellular boundary formula is defined as follows:

$\textbf{Cellular Boundary Formula}$:$d_n(e^{\alpha}_n) = \sum_{\beta}d_{\alpha\beta}e_{\beta}^{n-1}$
where $d_{αβ}$ is the degree of the
map $S^{n-1}_{\alpha} \rightarrow X^{n-1} \rightarrow S^{n-1}_{\beta}$
that is the composition of the attaching map of $e^n_{\alpha}$ with
the quotient map collapsing $X^{n-1}-e^{n-1}_{\beta}$
to a point.

I have problem understanding "collapsing $X^{n-1}-e^{n-1}_{\beta}$
to a point". Shouldn't we collapse  $X^{n-1}-int(e^{n-1}_{\beta})$ to a point where int denotes the interior?
For example, consider the 2-torus $T^2$, then it has $1$ $2$-cell, $2$ $1$-cells and $1$ $0$-cell. Let $e_1^1,e_1^2$ be the 2 $1$-cells.According to the cellular boundary formula, $X^{1}-e^{1}_{1} = S^1$. However, we know that $X_1$ is in fact a wedge of 2 circles and $X^{1}-e^{1}_{1}$ is hemeomorphic to an open interval. If we collapse it into a point, then we get a disjoint union of  point and circle, which doesn't seem right.
I might get the definition wrong but in this sense  is $X^{n-1}-e^{n-1}_{\beta}$ the same as
$X^{n-1}-int(e^{n-1}_{\beta})$ or it is an abuse of notation? Thank you very much.

For Hatcher $e$ is already the open cell so we don't need to discuss $\mathrm{int}(e_\beta^{n-1})$

@FShrike Ok I get it, thanks!
